# C# ASP.Net MVC image size not more than 1 MB

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an application which crops a picture and returns the result to the ViewModel as a base64 string. I need to check whether the size is within 1 MB or exceeds it.

This is my solution:

```
byte[] byteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(input);

if (byteArray.Length > Constants.PictureMaximumSize)
{      
    return false;
}    

return true;
```

Where: Constants.PictureMaximumSize = 1048576;

My Question:

I want to check if it is up to 1 MB - should I compare the byte [] length to 1048576 or maybe to 1000000?

Comment: So your question is just “how many bytes are in a megabyte?” Couldn’t you google that?

Comment: I did and got both results. So I am asking here for clarification.

Comment: Did you look up the reason why you got both results?

Comment: Yes, I read that 1048576 is in binary and the other in decimal metric system. And here we come to the example about the byteArray.Length - I am not sure which one to compare it to.

Comment: My opinion would be for 1048576 , but I would like to have some sure opinions on this.

Comment: `byteArray.Length` has nothing to do with it. You get to choose which is more appropriate to compare it to based on your use case. There is no "sure opinion".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In common computing usage 1,048,576 bytes is considered a megabyte. However, the standards bodies IEEE, EU, ISO and NIST only consider 1,000,000 bytes as a megabyte.

So, you get to choose which you want. Do you want to follow the international standards? Or do you want to remain consistent with almost every piece of software in existence? We can't choose for you, that's up to you. We can't tell you which one to use, you need to examine the information and make the correct choice for your application and its users.

Keep in mind that if you refer to [mebibyte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte), then you will be consistent with the international standards, and there is no ambiguity as to how many bytes are in a mebibyte, although that term is less well known and could be confusing to your users.

[Wikipedia has backstory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megabyte) on why both numbers are considered as a megabyte in various situations.

Comment: Thank you very much. 1,048,576 bytes would be my choice.